# Modifying File's CreationDate and ModificationDate Properties in Adobe Air

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I have written an Air program that mirrors a directory tree.  The problem is that the destination folder structure and content need to be identical - right down to the creationDate and modificaitonDate file attributes.  How can I change these file attributes using Adobe Air?

I'm able to READ them both just fine, but the properties are read-only.  How do I change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no API in Adobe Air for dealing with file attributes. You cannot set a file as read only or hidden, you cannot modify the creation and modification date. If you wish you can request a feature enhancement [here](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform).

Comment: Is there any link wherein your point is justified? I need to have a valid resource link for that. Thanks.

Comment: There is no API for that (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html). I've also asked the AIR engineers (they are in the same office with me). I do not have any other link.

Comment: That is so nice of you to help me clarify your answer. Thanks for your kind help :)